# how to do the same button for three screens?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have some trouble. So i have AvPlayer and UIButton with play/stop. 
Also: I have three UiViewControllers. I need that when I click on the first button on the first UIVIewController on the second controller, the third controller button is pressed also, respectively, on the contrary, too. How its make? Any proposition?

It's simple code - push on button - play URL Stream and also when push again stop music.

```
-(IBAction)playRadioButton:(id)sender
{
    if(clicked == 0) {    
        clicked = 1;
        NSLog(@"Play");
        NSString *urlAddress = @"http://URLRADIOSTREAM";
        NSURL *urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
        myplayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:urlStream];
        [myplayer play];
        [playRadioButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Stop");
        [myplayer release];
        clicked = 0;
        [playRadioButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks pretty good. What's the problem? I see only one button and no view controllers so far. Is the problem that if the user taps "Play" in one view controller and it changes to "Stop" and then moves to another view controller, the button should say "Stop" there also?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "I have three view controllers"? Do they all exist simultaneously (UITabBarController) or do they exist at various times (UINavigationController, presented view controller, etc.)? That makes a big difference, since you can't send a message to a view controller that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: What is there to understand? I have three screens. On the first screen I place the button and on the second and third too. When I press the button on the first screen, the second and third it should press too.

Comment: I did not put the code for the controller, it is simply not needed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several controllers that you need to notify about an event on another controller you can use `NSNotificationCenter`

Eg. in one controller in ViewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]    addObserver:self 
                                            selector:@selector(playBtnClicked:)
                                                name:@"BTN_CLICKED"
                                              object:nil];
```

Also in the same controller define the selector e.g.

```
-(void)playBtnClicked:(NSNotification *)pNotification
{
// do something
}
```

In the other controller trigger it by using

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                    postNotificationName:@"BTN_CLICKED" object:nil];
```

Comment: It's work! When i pushed on my button screen also changed and music played But i can not stop music from my play button from another controller...i insert in another ViewController in VievDidLoad this:[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                    postNotificationName:@"BTN_CLICKED" object:nil];

Comment: I guess you have to post another new question because I lost a little bit track and I am also not very familiar with the `AVPLAYER` class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use nsnotifications then use protocol and notify other viewcontrollers by using delegates

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are the 3 view controllers allocated and initialized at once? If not, I recommend you set a property on your `AppDelegate` class, like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL commonButtonPressed;
// All your code here

@end
```

And you can set this property like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.commonButtonPressed = YES; // or NO;
```

Then, from your `UIViewController` classes:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.commonButtonPressed) {

        // Logic of what happens to the button goes here.
    }
}
```

Another way of doing this, without touching your `AppDelegate` class is using `NSUserDefaults`, like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setBool:(<YES or NO>) forKey:@"commonButtonPressed"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize];
```

You can read back the value like this:

```
BOOL buttonPressed = [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] boolForKey:@"commonButtonPressed"];
```